# Python: Get max value from a multi-dimensional list

Tags: python, list, sorting, multidimensional-array, max

I wanna get max value of this list but faster than sorted.

```
[[1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [5, 2], [5, 3]]
```

I used to use sorted with key like this

```
bb = int(sorted(ab, key = lambda x:(int(x[1])))[-1][1])
```

For the result from this list

```
[[1, 1], [2, 1], [2, 2], [3, 2]]
```

I could get 3 and 2 which is max value of each line
But i took too much time so how can i speed it up?
And i wanna be able to set keys like sorted method, plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to sort the list (which would add a bunch of redundant operations). You could instead take the maximum of the maximums of the inner lists:

```py
lst = [[1, 3], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 1], [4, 2], [4, 3], [5, 2], [5, 3]]
result = max(max(l) for l in lst)
```

Comment: Not equivalent to the original (though that might be desired).

Comment: Comment on my post acknowledged, will have a closer look.  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: I mean, I want to get max value by line like lst[n][0] or something

Answer (score 1):

You can try using numpy, it should return 5 based on your list

```
import numpy as np

np.max(ab)
```

Comment: Nice simple solution.  Have you tested timing benchmarks against @Mureinik method? (Including the import of `numpy`)

Comment: I was about to post my time trial results, but I see you've already beat me to it :D